# notifyDataSetChanged for RecyclerView adapter is blocking the SwipeRefreshLayout indicator from cycling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am using RecyclerView with SwipeRefreshLayout and when the elements of RecyclerView increase, the notifyDataSetChanged blocks the indecator of SwipeRefreshLayout from cycling animation until the binding finished.

I have tired the following solutions but no success:

1. [How to use notifyDataSetChanged() in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665676/how-to-use-notifydatasetchanged-in-thread) "using ui thread still blocking the animation"
2. [RecyclerView blocking ui thread during updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608590/recyclerview-blocking-ui-thread-during-updates) "optimizing update data set by update only the changed items will
   only minimize the blocking time but did not solve issue"

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter
also use item Ids

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply updating one part of the view, use the `notifyItemRangeChanged()`or `notifyItemChanged()` instead of `notifiyDataSetChanged()`.

try `notifyItemChanged()`

Comment: This will not avoid blocking the UI it could only minimize the time being blocked.